# MS Sync Framework Client Server Scenario with two SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

As far as I understand the Client Server Scenario (aka Offline Scenario) it is supposed to use with a SQL Server as Server and a SQL Server **Compact** as Client.
I have to implement a synchronization between a master and several nodes where the nodes communicate and synchronize with the master but not with each other. Master and Nodes are all SQL Server 2008.

Is it possible (and does it make sense) to use the MS Sync Framework for this scenario?

When I set up a Client Server synchronization there is only a `SqlCeClientSyncProvider` (Note the **Ce**) but no `SqlClientSyncProvider` (without *Ce*)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sync Framework targets Occasionally Connected Systems. In OCS the subscribers connect sporadically, at different locations, and under different network identities. It is always the client that initiates the synchronization (because it knows when is connected) and the synchronization occurs via a HTTP gateway. Think mobile and hand held devices. synchronizing with a central server.

For tightly connected systems when the subscriber is more or less always connected and keeps a consistent network identity a better fit is Replication (transactional, merge).

That being said, there is a [SQL Express Client Sync Provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=sync&ReleaseId=1200) sample at Code Gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Hey the syncFramework may be overkill for your scenario.. you may simply want to try SQL Server Replication. Here is some [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(SQL.90).aspx).  Basically SQL Server already has the ability to create replication Publications (snapshot, transactional, and merge) then you simply add your subscribers.  Subscribers will replicate with the master and the master will replicate with the subscribers.  you can choose to replicate an entire db or just a few tables.  Take a look.